# trying to get a form output on a request

Tags: php, html, loops

I am trying to get values from a form but on Submit request. Bellow is just the PHP code as I know that the HTML Form is correct as it worked perfectly when I did not place the `isset()` function into the PHP.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $emailstr = $_POST['email'];
        $postaddrstr =$_POST['postaddr'];
        $favsportstr =$_POST['favsport'];
        $emailliststr =$_POST['emaillist'];
    }
?>
```

I believe the error lies somewhere in the below part as i am getting an undefined variable message for $val and an Array to string conversion at the foreach loop.

```
<section id="output">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
            echo "<h2>The following information was received from the form:</h2>";
            echo "<p><strong>First Name:</strong>   $fname </p>";

            echo "<p><strong>Email = </strong>   $emailstr </p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Post Address = </strong>   $postaddrstr </p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Your Favourit Sport:</strong> 
            foreach($favsportstr as $val) {
                $val 
            }";
            echo "<p><strong>Email list = </strong>   $emailliststr </p>";
        }
    ?>
</section>
```

Comment: write your `foreach` outside of `echo`

Comment: your basic syntax is incorrect. you close the echo, then run the foreach, with echo inside

Comment: Sorry yah i got it. The foreach loop goes out of echo and the $val will have an echo with it. Thank you Smith and R B.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write loops inside `echo` change following line:

```
 echo "<p><strong>Your Favourit Sport:</strong> 
 foreach($favsportstr as $val) {
       $val 
 }";
```

to

```
 echo "<p><strong>Your Favourit Sport:</strong> ";
 foreach($favsportstr as $val) {
      echo $val;
 }
```

Comment: `implode(",",$favsportstr)` would be nice for `['foo','bar']` to `foo,bar` instead `foobar`

Answer (score 0):

This is where your error comes from:

```
echo "<p><strong>Your Favourit Sport:</strong> 
            foreach($favsportstr as $val) {
                $val 
            }";
```

Just change it to this and it will be fine:

```
echo "<p><strong>Your Favourit Sport:</strong>"; 
            foreach($favsportstr as $val) {
                echo $val; 
            }
```

The reason is you can't put a loop inside an echo statement. Put echo inside the loop not the loop inside echo. 'echo' statement is just for printing the output. It wont support any processing it will just print everything inside it. It can only output the variable values when they are placed between double quotes. Like this : `echo "$var";`